# Express res.render not working with Angular routing

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, angular-routing

I have a web app based on node.js, express, angular (with routes) and mongo. Authentication is handled through Passport.js.

My angular views interact with the server through http requests. Say I send a request of type:

```
$http.get('/api/getMyData').success(function(data) {})...
```

on the server I have:

```
 app.get('/api/getMyData',function(req, res) {
    if(!req.user){
    // if the session expired
    res.render('login.ejs',{message:'Session expired. Please login again.'});
```

With this code I would like the user to be redirected to the login page if the session has expired.

Now, this is not working, and I get not redirected to login. Even if I have `console.log(req.user)` producing `undefined` and `req.user==undefined` giving `true`, the `res.render` within the `if` does not work. And if I try with `res.redirect('login');`
I get a 404 error saying that `/api/login` does not exist.

I am really getting lost with this, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: don't you mean res.render? (your title)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented something similar to what @Jordonias suggested. 
I get the user from the server (`null` if the session expired), 
and if the user is `null` I use `$window.location.href="/login";` to logout the user.
Thanks to @Jordonias. Better alternatives are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Your `$http.get()` is getting the contents back from `res.render()`.
You can see this by adding `console.log(data);` in `$http.get().success()`
You'll need to add some logic to your client to redirect if there is an error from the api.

Something like:

**server.js**

```
app.get('/api/getMyData', function(req, res) {
  if(!req.user) {
    res.status(401);
    return res.json({
      status: 'error',
      message: 'Unauthorized'
    });
  }
  return res.json({
    status: 'success',
    // Stuff
  });
}
```

Angular

```
$http.get('/api/getMyData').success(function(data) {
  // Do something
}).error(function(data, status) {
  // Handle the error
});
```

Note: This is untested but it will give you a general idea. There may be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I see this could be a solution.
Say that I get a json with status: error, how could I then redirect from angular to a login page like login.ejs, with a certain message (the think I wanted to do in the if in the original post)?
In any case I still don't get why res.render does not work in this case.

Comment: Create a route for **login.ejs** (/login) and do something like `$location.path(url);` then `$scope.$apply();`